# How to get both like and dislike count of the post in single query using cake php or php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have researched a day but I not get the solution.if it is possible to get he likes and dislike count of all post using single CakePHP query
table structure

```
id user_id  posts_id  like_and_dislike
1    1         1          1
2    2         1          1
3    4         1          0
4    5         2          1
```

Here we need to get the like and dislike count of all posts that is for 
post 1 like -> 2 and dislike -> 1 And for post - 2 like -> 1 and dislike -> 0
need to list the count.please any one help on this query if it not possible please help in php query

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result? (As well formatted text.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I need an output as {[{"posts_id":1,"likes":"2","dislike":"1"},{"posts_id":2,"likes":"1","dislike":"null"}]}

Comment: And I tried  sql query particuler post 14 but I need to list all posts

SELECT * , (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM users_like_posts WHERE posts_id = 14 AND like_or_dislike = '0' GROUP BY realtime_id ) as dislike,
(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM users_like_posts WHERE realtime_id = 14 AND like_or_dislike = '1' GROUP BY realtime_id) as postlike FROM users_like_posts INNER JOIN posts ON users_like_posts.posts_id = posts.id WHERE posts_id = 14 GROUP BY posts_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guess you need this

```
SELECT post_id, 
COUNT( CASE WHEN like_and_dislike = 1 THEN 1 END ) AS like_cnt, 
COUNT( CASE WHEN like_and_dislike = 0 THEN 1 END ) AS dislike_cnt 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY post_id
-- ORDER BY something
-- LIMIT x, y
```

Comment: There's an example for pretty much exactly that in the docs btw: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements**

Comment: @ndm - I never looked cakephph documentation, though it's not surprising for me, that there is similar example, because this SQL approach is very common in situations like this

Comment: @OtoShavadze one more calrification how to use the LIMIT for this query

Comment: @RaghulRajendran - What do you need to limited, please tell this more clearly

Comment: @OtoShavadze The query return the array of values no problem in that.i need to customly limit the array
for exampe SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 30
for implementing paginate the result

Comment: @RaghulRajendran - You can simply add `LIMIT x, y` clause, but also, do you need ALWAYS to use `ORDER BY some_criteria`, for guaranteed sorting of rows. Also, if you need implement this with `cakephp`, may be better will be ask another question "how to implement pagination in cakephp" or something similar. I don't know about this framework almost anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139762/discussion-between-raghul-rajendran-and-oto-shavadze).

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

- [Use the CounterCache](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html#namespace-Cake%5CORM%5CBehavior) behavior
- [Or do two sub-queries](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#subqueries) to get the counts in the same query, which is less efficient